# My Mozilla Firefox is kinda buggy. What could be the reason?

Tags: firefox

My Mozilla Firefox is behaving weird lately. I don't know how to explain this so I posted a photo below. This happens **only when I open two or more TABS**. When one tab is opened everything looks fine. But when I open another tab I can see small squares that are changing their position and show mostly in the navigation toolbar but sometimes also inside the browser (as in this case).

I have no clue what this could be. I tried to update my Firefox, than completely uninstall it and instal everything from scratch. Nothing changed.

This doesn't show up in Internet Explorer 11 or in latest Chrome but only in Firefox.

I guess it might be some other program that is associated with Firefox but I can't find the solution.

If anyone has had similar experience please let me know how you solved it.

P.S. Hope you can see the small squares on this photo. I marked them with the red arrows.

[image: Buggy Firefox]

Answer (score 1):

Run an antivirus, it might solve the problem. If not, then uninstall firefox and run an antivirus. If this does not solve the problem, then save the important data on a different drive, reinstall the operating system and install firefox. Note, that the virus database used by the antivirus should be new.

Comment: Ok. I will try as you said. I am using Avast and have never had any problems with viruses so far. Thanks for your reply! Hope someone else will answer with different solution so I can try everything before reinstalling operating system.

Comment: I believe you have a virus. If you search for the behavior you experience, then you might get some info as about what to do to manually get rid of it from the registry. In some cases the antivirus is not aware about the virus, which could be well-implemented as well, unfortunately.

Comment: I ran a full system scan for viruses with Avast and wait to see what will happen. DOes it matter if my Firefox is open and I am using it?

Comment: The antivirus should detect the problem anyway, but might be unable to solve the problem if the system is running. Maybe you could run the antivirus in safe mode.

Comment: My full system scan for viruses showed nothing.  I mean, no viruses. I also installed all the latest important and unimportant Windows updates, I updated all the programs I am using on my computer like Java, Adobe Flash Player, Google Chrome, IE, 7Zip, Skype, VLC... etc. Nothing helped so far. I really hate to reinstall the whole Windows so if you think there is something else I can do before doing this I would be willing to try. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: If I were you, I would bite the bullet and would reinstall the OS. That takes a day or so if you add a lot of things and it surely solves the problem.

Comment: I guess that's the only thing left to do. But I don't have the installation disc because my Windows 7 came originally installed with my laptop. I guess there is an option to do refresh somewhere just gotta find it... Btw, since I installed all of the latest important and unimportant Windows updates my computer is slower than it was before... Alright, thank you very much for your time and suggestions! Appreciate it a lot.

Comment: This is how you can install Windows 7 without disk: http://www.pcworld.com/article/248995/how-to-install-windows-7-without-the-disc.html. Here is how you can selectively install windows updates for windows 8: http://all4naija.blogspot.ro/2013/01/how-to-do-selective-installation-of.html. Maybe it is possible for windows 7 as well. If my answer was helpful, you might consider accepting it, so people in the future having similar problems will see that their problem was already discussed.

Comment: I still haven't solved the 'buggy' issue with my Mozilla Firefox browser. That's why I haven't accepted your answer so far. Otherwise your answers were definitely helpful and I value your time and effort very much. To be honest I am kinda afraid to do this re-installation of my Windows 7 just because of this issues with Firefox. It is buggy and it is annoying but I don't want to make it worse. If I do such a step and it solves the problem I will definitely come back and accept your answer so that the community here can see the solution. Thanks again!

Comment: Also, I forgot to mention that when I hover with my mouse pointer over the 'bugs' in my browser the bugs disappear! So crazy.

Comment: Reinstallation should solve the problem, however, you are obviously sacrificing a lot of time if you do not have a working save of your system before of the problem (and, unfortunately, that is the case). As a result, you will either find the exact cause, or, you will have to reinstall the system. If you want to choose the former, then I recommend bugzilla. Here I have searched for display bug, but you can search for other terms or create your own ticket to report the bug.

Comment: Ok. Today I turned off Windows Aero feature and the result is - significant improvement. There were just one or two very small bugs but comparing this with what was before it's a great improvement. Now I wonder why are these bugs showing (only!) in Mozilla Firefox when multiple tabs are opened and when Windows Aero feature is turned on? Also, my laptop is 3 years and 8 months old and these bugs never showed up during first 3 years. I have 6GB of RAM so that shouldn't be a problem. Could it be that my Graphic Card is 'dying'??? Hope not!

Comment: I do not believe it is a hardware problem, since in most of cases, the hardware problem shows up in different applications. I suspect that FireFox is not the only application inducing the hardware problem. However, 6 GB is not too much. You could test your hardware by playing a game. If the problem does not show up, then we can rule out this possibility. You can also bring your laptop to a service and ask them to test it with added memory. They will surely help you.

Comment: I finally solved my problem with the help from Mozilla Support! The solution was quite simple: I just had to turn off (uncheck) the 'Use hardware acceleration when available' box. It is located in the Firefox Menu > Options > Advanced > General. Now everything runs normal and w/o bugs. Not sure if this is going to impact the speed and performance of my browser. I'll see. Anyway, thanks for your help!

Comment: I am happy it turned out to be a setting issue, that's wonderful.

Answer (score 1):

Try create a new profile, here the support information:

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/profile-manager-create-and-remove-firefox-profiles

Comment: Thanks for suggestion. I will read what the link says and see if this will be helpful.